# Changing DNS server globally in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, dns, network-adapter

It is possible to change DNS server for a particular network adapter in Windows. But is it possible make global settings like Linux so I don't have to change it for every network adapter?

Comment: Nope, DNS server settings are per-adapter.  You could make a script that changes them all though, if that's an acceptable solution, but more information on why you need to do this (and what you've already tried) may help bring other solutions to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

If,you are a home user try to update it in the router. Or what's your primary requirement? You,need to update all the dns server ip for all adapters by one click?? Simple install a bind dns server in ur machine and set the resover to 8.8.8.8 or ur dns ip and,set the adapter dns records to local ip 127.0.0.1